# Were RMS Lancastria survivors strafed?

Tags: world-war-two, war-crime, dunkirk

The bombing and sinking of *RMS Lancastria* popped up in the "on this day" Wikipedia feed.

[RMS Lancastria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Lancastria)

In the article there is this paragraph:

> When German aircraft began strafing survivors in the water[citation
>   needed], the fuel oil which had leaked into the sea ignited, and was
>   quickly transformed into a flaming inferno[citation needed]. Many
>   drowned; others were choked by the oil, or were shot by strafing
>   German aircraft.[citation needed]

The frequent `[citation needed]` sets off alarm bells. I couldn't find anything else on this topic. The Wikipedia Talk page makes no mention, nor do the references cited.

One of the sources mention that it was actually flares set off by survivors who ignited the oil, leading to the inferno.

My question: is there any confirmed information that the Luftwaffe went for *targeted* strafing of survivors?

Note: this excludes "general strafing" by German aircraft against beaches and vessels to hinder the evacuation of BEF and French forces.

Or is this just one of those Wikipedia things - made up out of whole cloth?

Comment: Farther down you'll find "_Those who got away were machine gunned in the water".[14]_" You might want to follow footnote 14 (registration required).

Comment: I was more curious about any inquiries, trials, maybe even orders given to Luftwaffe units (indiscriminate strafing), etc. The issue being that a surviving crew member in the water would not have been able to distinguish "getting caught up" in the general strafing, vs targeted attempts at those in the water - which I believe would have constituted a war crime (IANAL).

Comment: I followed a couple of the links to other sources on the sinking, including eyewitness accounts, and found a suspicious absence of "strafing" being mentioned. (The bombers that sunk the ship wouldn't have been able to "strafe" in the first place, and I don't think the Luftwaffe would bother sending fighters to find a shipwreck at sea and shoot at survivors.) I consider that paragraph about strafed survivors to be **highly** suspect. Perhaps that source [14] mentions it, but you'd think the others would, too, if it actually happened.

Comment: the topic of shooting at survivors comes up in  Hanns Scharffs book "the interrogator"  and it boils down to the fact there were sociopaths flying on both sides that did this sort of thing, but it was not the policy of either to actively engage in this.

Comment: I had never heard of Hans Scharff and am quite intrigued, based on the Wiki article! Going to see if I can get my hands on that. Thanks!

Comment: @Marakai - its is a fascinating book, i highly recommend it.  it is primarily about the methods Scharff used to get allied pilots to talk (without knowing they "talked")  but near the end of the book he is investigating the case of an American pilot that strafed a hospital.  his conclusions were basically what i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Lancastria#:%7E:text=According%20to%20Jonathan,Cambridgeshire%20rescuing%20900.) on the RMS Lancastria says:

> According to Jonathan Fenby in his book [The Sinking of the
> Lancastria](https://www.rareaviationbooks.com/pages/books/1682/jonathan-fenby/the-sinking-of-the-lancastria-britains-greatest-maritime-disaster-and-churchills-cover-up), the German aircraft strafed survivors in the water.
> Survivors were taken aboard other British and Allied evacuation
> vessels, the trawler HMT Cambridgeshire rescuing 900.

- Britannica

Although I do not think that the Luftwaffe Intentionally targeted to strafe.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what *Fenby's* sources were. The further such an event has been since, the more likely that "what the internet knows" has found it's way back into the publication. (Point in case: I've seen a poorly worded primary source about some regional locality lead to a even poorer worded paragraph on Wikipedia, which was in turn presented as "fact" in a book *by the city in question*...)

Comment: Plus, note my comment under the Q. The bombers hitting the Lancastria were Ju-88. The vast majority of Ju-88 in use at the time (A and D series) were armed with 7.92mm machine guns. That's not the kind of armament that lends itself to "strafing", let alone setting a fuel slick on fire... The A-14 variant, built with improved armor and intended to be used against maritime targets, sported one 20mm cannon. Still not exactly making it worthwhile to loiter in the target area shooting at swimmers. That's why I am doubting the "strafing" narrative.